# Count of digits from char array varies with same input in Java

Tags: java, arrays, performance, char, inputstream

I need to load big amount of digits from console, separated with whitespaces and my result should count number of digits within the input. These can be all numbers from 0 to 10^9.

Code below works for smaller input, but for data like in file [here](https://ufile.io/572be) it shows wrong result, what's more it is different with every execution (for attached file it should be 968364).

What am I doing wrong? I can't use any methods or classes within the loop, it has to work on primitive types, but apparently I'm missing something.

Please help, thanks in advance for any tips.

```
int input_size = 0;
        char[] input = new char[1000000];
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            in.read(input);
            for(int a = 0; a<input.length; a++){
                if (input[a] >= 48 && input[a] <= 57){
                    input_size ++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(input_size);
```

Comment: you only read 1 million characters, but your input file has +1,1 million characters, so you're missing about 10% of the input file

Comment: Yes, I corrected it, but it still doesn't solve my problem

Comment: view my Answer, it works for me just fine and i get the correct output(968364).

Comment: I see that, but you read data from file, in my case all data comes from console. I modified it to work that way, but it shows incorrect results.
`int input_size = 0;  
  int readChars;  
  char[] input = new char[10000];  
      InputStreamReader in = new   InputStreamReader(System.in);  
     do{
      readChars = in.read(input);    
      for(int a = 0; a<readChars; a++){
       if (Character.isDigit(input[a])){
        input_size ++;
       }
      }
     } while (readChars == input.length);
      in.close();
   System.out.println(input_size);
 }`

Comment: I added a line, which you only have to uncomment so you can switch between a Reader from the Console and a Reader from a file - i tested my code with your data and it resulted in the correct output

Comment: I literally copy paste your code, and it doesn't work. I test it in eclipse by pasting test data to console. I wrote code based on String arrray and that one works perfectly fine, however it's way too slow

Comment: i double checked and it still works - with the file *and* the console input...hmm... did you copy my answer or maybe the other one? or what exactly is not working? is it the wrong count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not read the whole file, I edited your code so it reads the input in chunks of 1000 chars until it is finished

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    char[] input = new char[1000];
    int input_size = 0;
    int readChars;

    //Reader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    Reader in = new FileReader("572be-stud3.txt");
    do {
        readChars = in.read(input);
        for (int a = 0; a < readChars; a++) {
            if (input[a] >= 48 && input[a] <= 57) {
                input_size++;
            }
        }
    } while((readChars < 0) || (input[readChars-1] != '\n'));
    in.close();

    System.out.println(input_size);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things, first [`in.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read-char:A-) returns the number of characters it read. You need to store that, because the default value for an `int` (in an `int[]` is `0`). Next, you can use `'0'` and `'9'` instead of hardcoding your valid ascii values - but I would prefer [`Character.isDigit(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-). Like,

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
int readLen = in.read(input);
for (int a = 0; a < readLen; a++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(input[a])) {
        input_size++;               
    }
    // if (input[a] >= '0' && input[a] <= '9') {
    // input_size++;
    // }
}
System.out.println(input_size);
```

Comment: I changed condition in "if" to what you suggested. But still the input_size value keep returning different values, I also have a file where are 2400120 digits, results are wrong every time. When I display result of int x = in.read(input); it shows that every time it loads only some part of data. I increased array size to 10 mln but it still doesn't work as should. I have no idea why it works this way..

Comment: Did you also use `readLen`? Because that is really the most important thing here, your array is full of `10,000,000` zeros by default (and has a fixed length).